# Error with openstack server list command

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

I installed Openstack on my CentOs VM and when i try to see the list of launched instances, i get this error

```
$ openstack server list

Ignoring domain related config user_domain_name because identity API version is 2.0
Ignoring domain related config user_domain_name because identity API version is 2.0
Ignoring domain related config user_domain_name because identity API version is 2.0
Ignoring domain related config user_domain_name because identity API version is 2.0
Expecting to find domain in user - the server could not comply with the request since it is either malformed or otherwise incorrect. The client is assumed to be in error. (HTTP 400) (Request-ID: req-453d115d-afc8-4ea0-9c2a-4f55fd7591ba)
```

Can someone tell me how to change the user_domain_name?

Comment: I believe you are using the Keystone v2. In v2, there is no notion of domain. Domains are included in the V3 of Keystone (keystone is the identity manager btw). So my guess is that your nova is trying to make v3 calls but some of the parameters get ignored since they are not managed by your old version of Keystone. Can you check what version of keystone you are using? You may have to update it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I figured out what was missing in my current openstack credentials. I am posting these if someone has the same problem as mine.

```
OS_PROJECT_DOMAIN_NAME="your domain name"
OS_IDENTITY_API_VERSION=3
```